# How to extract string of command result and use it in a loop

Tags: bash, docker, shell, awk, sh

Running a `nx affected:apps` command gives me this output:

```
>  NX   NOTE  Affected criteria defaulted to --base=master --head=HEAD


>  NX  Affected apps:

  - app-backend
  - app-frontend
  - app-something
  - app-anything
```

I need to get all the application names and use them again for a command call.

So I started with that

```
output=$(nx affected:apps)  
echo "$output" | grep -E "^\W+app-(\w+)"
```

This gives me

```
- app-backend
- app-frontend
- app-something
- app-anything
```

But I need to get the names only instead to run `foo --name={appname}` four times.
Also not quite sure how to use it in a loop. Quite new to bash scripting :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `--plain` option:

```
nx affected:apps --plain
```

the command should return all the affected apps with space as a divider. You can then store those to a bash array and cycle through them in a for loop, running the command you need:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
AFFECTED=($(./node_modules/.bin/nx affected:apps --plain))

for t in ${AFFECTED[@]}; do
    echo $t
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `-o` (show matches only) with `-P` (perl regex moode) in `gnu-grep`:

```
nx affected:apps |
grep -oP "^\W+app-\K\w+" |
xargs -I {} docker build -t {} .
```

---

If `gnu-grep` isn't available then use this `awk` command:

```
nx affected:apps |
awk -F- '/app-/{print $3}' |
xargs -I {} docker build -t {} .
```

Comment: Two questions on that: How do I use the result as parameters for another command call? And it seems not to work in that way on a mac machine, right? I'm developing on a mac machine, but the script should run on a ubuntu server later...

Comment: Just like `docker build -t $appname` So in this case I would build four docker images

Comment: nearly working. But there is no content for the `-t` parameter. So for the first matching line the command should be `docker build -t backend .`

Comment: You can put any command after `xargs -n1` and it will pass one line each time from previous command. If you tell me full `docker build` command line then I can tweak it in answer.

Comment: Full command is simple `docker build -t backend .` while `backend` is the first match.

Comment: That is a `replace-str`. `xargs` replaces occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input. More details available in `max xargs`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `nx` command here but you can try using `xargs`:

```
nx affected:apps | grep '^  -' | cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs  -I{}  echo docker build -t {} ./dist/{}
```

Remove `echo` to actually run the command.

Comment: Running this doesn't give me any output. I don't see a docker command...

Comment: You need to remove `echo` to actually *run* docker. You should just see `docker build -t app-backend ./dist/app-backend` print on the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that. I don't get any result printed on the screen. I would have expected (with your answer) to see four docker cmd without calling these...

Comment: ok, I see. What does `nx affected:apps | grep '^-' | cut -d' ' -f2` itself show? Are there whitespaces before `-` in `nx` output?

Comment: Also nothing. It is taking a second (as nx is called), but it doesn't give an output.

Comment: That would mean that there are either whitespaces in front of `-` or that `nx` is writing to standard error.

Comment: Oh, you are right, there are white spaces in front if `-`. I did not recognize that. My fault.

Comment: Got it. But the output is `docker build -t - ./dist/-`. So it seems to be the wrong match.

Comment: Are there 2 whitespaces before `-`? See updated answer.